# find specific files and copy them to a directory in linux

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression, filenames

```
abc-1.0.zip
kncb-1.0.zip
jenk-1.1.zip
```

I want to find all the above files dynamically and copy them to a directory except jenk-1.1.zip. I have tried the below command but it also copies  file(jenk*.zip), need a command which copies all the above files except jenk-1.1.zip to a directory mentioned (test_dir);

```
find . \( -name *abc*.zip-o -name *knc*.zip ! -name "*jenk*.zip"\)  ! -path '*/test_dir/*.jar' -exec cp -ar {} ./test_dir \;
```

Comment: if you're specifically matching "abc-1.0.zip" or "kncb-1.0.zip" why even bother excluding "jenk-1.1.zip"? It'll never match the preceding names...

Answer (score 0):

```
 -iname *.zip
```

is looking for all zip files

```
! -iname "jen*.zip"
```

is ignoring all jenk* files

If you're looking for just zip files, there is no need to exclude jar files. If you search for files (`find -type f`) there is no need for the `cp -r` switch (recursive))

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.zip" ! -iname "jen*.zip" \) -exec cp -av {} ~/test \;
```

Comment: That will copy all zip files except for the one starting with `jenk`. It's not a problem if those are the only three zip files in the entire directory including the subdirectories but if they aren't then it'll be too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name abc-1.0.zip -o -name kncb-1.0.zip) test_dir
```

Run that from the directory where the files reside. If you want to descend into subdirectories, remove `maxdepth 1`.

Comment: This looks correct, but might not work for `abc-1.1.zip` if OP works with versions.

Comment: He's not trying copy abc-1.1.zip.